# Recursive AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, recursion, tree, angularjs-filter

I have a tree structure [like this](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/03e9bdeda4edc82fdb6d) stored in the `$scope.tree` object. I want to create a filter, that I could apply to this tree to shrink it to [this](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/8741e5a7d018263bc5f1) to be able to do smth like this `$scope.cut_tree = $filter('cutTree')($scope.tree)` and get that minified output.

But I have really no idea how to do that, everything I've tried so far does not get me anywhere, 'cause I end up changing the $scope.tree itself.

**UPDATE**

What I have so far:

```
app.filter("filterTree", ["$filter", function($filter) {
    return function(tree) {
      var newTree = [];
      angular.forEach(tree, function(node, index) {
        var newNode;
        newNode = {
          id: node.id,
          sort_order: index,
          children: $filter('filterTree')(node.children)
        };
        newTree.push(newNode);
      });
      return newTree;
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: First of all if you don't want to modify the original tree, I'd work with a local copy of the tree using angular.copy (`var treeCopy = angular.copy(tree);`)

Comment: I figured it would be easier to initialize an empty tree inside the filter and push filtered objects there. Otherwise I'll end up having lots and lots of copies.

Comment: Javascript objects are passed by reference, you will have to copy each property of the tree and create new objects when necessary if you don't want to modify your original tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a working example in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Vqk/296/).

The filter used is the following :

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('cutTree', ['$filter',function ($filter) {
    return function (tree) {
        var res = [];
        var sortOrder=0;
        angular.forEach(tree, function(item) {
            // Deep copy

           var copy = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(item))
           res.push({
               id:copy.id,
               sort_order:sortOrder,
               children:$filter('cutTree')(item.children)
           })
           sortOrder++;
     });
        return res;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured almost the same way. Now it'll be interesting to play with on my own.

Answer (score 1):

It should be relatively easy to make a recursive function that only copies over the field you want. for example

```
var cutTree = function(original){
    var result = {};
    result.id = original.id;
    result.name = original.name;
    result.children = [];

    for (var i=0; i<original.children.length; i++)
    {
        result.children.push(cutTree(original.children[i]));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you only need to define a filter that will call this function and return its result.